# Bash Script not executing git pull

Tags: laravel, bash, git, shell, ubuntu

I'm executing a bash script from laravel controller using `symphony/process`. The bash script is executing but only few of the lines only. Other lines are throwing no output at all.

This is what I'm using to execute bash script from laravel controller.

```
        $process = new Process(['/home/ubuntu/deploy.sh']);
          process->run();
        if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
            throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
        }
        echo $process->getOutput();
```

This is triggering the deploy.sh file. and the code of deploy.sh is :

```
#!/bin/sh  
cd /var/www/foodie #working
# activate maintenance mode 
php artisan down  #working
# update source code 
git pull --progress #not working
# update PHP dependencies 
composer install --no-interaction --no-dev --prefer-dist  #not working
# --no-interaction Do not ask any interactive question 
# --no-dev Disables installation of require-dev packages. 
# --prefer-dist Forces installation from package dist even for dev versions. 
# update database 
php artisan migrate --force #working
# --force Required to run when in production. 
# stop maintenance mode 
php artisan up #working
```

In all the code php based commands and `cd` command only working. All other not getting exeuted.

When I execute same file like `/home/ubuntu/deploy.sh` all commands are working.

I have tried executing the same code manually with `home/deploy/deploy.sh` and all working fine.

I'm expecting the same should work when executed through `symphony/process` from laravel controller.

Comment: Who is the owner of `.git/` and all its contents? You may have this problem: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1433060/git-fatal-detected-dubious-ownership-in-repository. Changing the owner of `.git/` i.e. `chown -R -c www-data:www-data -- .git` may solve the issue. Note: As the owner will not be your own user after this, executing those scripts manually may not work anymore, unless you prefix `sudo -u www-data` to your commands.

Comment: When debugging shell scripts, if you add `set -x` at the top (e.g. second line or thereabouts) it will print each command it executes, so it is easier to correlate output and what is/is not happening.

Comment: If the Git interactions require a password and your script is running in a context where it doesn't have access to your secrets, that's the explanation right there.